# When using Mapbox within a webapp, is there a limit to the number of geoJSON polygons that can be downloaded as a single KML or Shapefile bundle?

Tags: geojson, kml, hexagonal-tiles, kmz, multipolygons

We are launching our MVP prototype application using Mapbox for the map display. This map will display multi-polygon layers as geoJSON and may include dozens or even hundreds of polygons. We are evaluating using a hex bin style map similar to this GGPlot method (https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_hex.html).

We are encountering issues trying to provide users with a download as KML option and cannot find very clear developer syntax for interacting with Mapbox API to perform this multi-polygon download.

Where can we find better guidance for how to handle hundreds of polygons simultaneously and whether there are limits to these?

Using GG Plot for render of data in hex bin map style: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_hex.html

Looking at these references for methods to convert to KML:

https://github.com/mapbox/tokml/blob/master/README.md

https://github.com/mapbox/tokml